# Import cannot be resolved by test plugin fragment using Tycho but works in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, osgi, tycho

I have a plugin project which I am trying to create a test plugin for. The packages in my plugin project are available to other plugins in my workspace, including the test plugin, but when I try and build my projects using tycho the test plugin is throwing an error stating that the import cannot be resolved.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:0.25.0:compile (default-compile) on project REDACTED.tests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] REDACTED/PlanImportTest.java:[7]
[ERROR] import REDACTED.pluginname.Argument;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The import REDACTED.pluginname cannot be resolved
```

I am new to Tycho so I think there is probably an issue with my project layout, but I can't find a solution to my problem online. Does anyone know why this import is working in eclipse but not when running a maven/tycho build on the command line? Relevant files below.

**Plugin manifest:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: REDACTED.pluginname
Bundle-SymbolicName: REDACTED.pluginname;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Export-Package: REDACTED
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: REDACTED
```

**Plugin POM:**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>REDACTED</groupId>
        <artifactId>REDACTED</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>REDACTED</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>REDACTED</groupId>
    <artifactId>REDACTED.pluginname</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>
```

**Test class**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import REDACTED.pluginname.Argument;

public class PlanImportTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Argument a = null;
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

**Test project manifest:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: REDACTED
Bundle-SymbolicName: REDACTED.tests
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: REDACTED
Fragment-Host: REDACTED.pluginname;bundle-version="1.0.0.qualifier"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Require-Bundle: org.junit;bundle-version="4.12.0"
```

**Test project POM:**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>REDACTED</groupId>
        <artifactId>REDACTED</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>REDACTED</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>REDACTED</groupId>
    <artifactId>REDACTED.tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testClass>REDACTED.Test</testClass>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                            <groupId>REDACTED</groupId>
                            <artifactId>REDACTED.pluginname</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: There should be no need to explicitly declare dependencies in the test project pom. Instead, your parent pom should list both projects as ' modules'.

Comment: Ah yeah I am already doing that and the pluginname module is being loaded successfully first. I will remove this plugin from the pom, it was something I tried in addition to other things to hope to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that my plugin to be tested was not exporting the source directory correctly. A change to the build.properties file fixed this:

Before:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               src/
output.. = bin
```

After:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               src/
source.. = src
output.. = bin
```

So simple but I got there in the end.

Answer (score 2):

as you are using a fragment, the additional dependency to the fragment host in pom.xml should not be needed.

One thing that seems incomplete in your question to me is the use of buddy classloading. In case the classes you are compiling against are actually provided by a buddy of the bundle under test (not by the bundle itself), you may have to add an extraRequirement to the buddy(ies), see https://eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#dependencies

For debugging purposes, you can use maven CLI option -X which will dump the bundles which were calculated to be included in the test runtime. This way you can spot if there is a bundle missing.

Comment: Does this mean I also need to add the buddy of the plugin under test to the list of modules built by the reactor pom?

Comment: I removed the buddy from the plugin under test to try and see if I can isolate the problem, but I am still getting the same error as before. I also removed the fragment from the test plugin pom. For mvn -X should I be looking in the classpath? If so that is showing my project:
[DEBUG] Output directory: REDACTED.tests/target/classes
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  REDACTED.tests/target/classes
**[DEBUG]  REDACTED.pluginname/.**
[DEBUG]  /home/developer/.m2/repository/.cache/tycho/org.junit-4.12.0.v201504281640.jar...